# Error 403 when sending a post request to a site with Python

Tags: python, python-requests

So I am coding a simple script for a site that adds the product to the cart and then checks out. The script was working fine and I decided to rewrite it so the code was cleaner, but now I am facing a problem when making the post request to add the product to my cart which I was not facing before and the site hasn't changed anything. I think there might be a problem with my headers but I don't see anything else. This is my code.

```
import requests, re

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36',
    'origin': 'https://www.colorskates.com',
    'connection': 'keep-alive',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
}

s = requests.Session()

product = input('What shoe would you like to run for: ')
size = input('What size would you like to run for: ')

sizes = {
    '35': 37,
    '36': 7,
    '36.5': 24,
    '37': 8,
    '37.5': 9,
    '38': 10,
    '38.5': 22,
    '39': 11,
    '40': 12,
    '40 2/3': 187,
    '40.5': 84,
    '41': 13,
    '41 1/3': 188,
    '42': 14,
    '42 2/3': 189,
    '42.5': 15,
    '43': 16,
    '43 1/3': 190,
    '44': 17,
    '44 2/3': 191,
    '44.5': 21,
    '45': 18,
    '45 1/3': 192,
    '45.5': 39,
    '46': 19,
    '46.5': 147,
    '47': 47,
    '47.5': 117,
    '48': 48,
    '48.5': 85,
    '49.5': 177
}

product_atc = product  + '?action=add_product'
product_ids = int(re.search(r'\d+', product).group(0))

atc = s.post(product_atc, data={'id[2]': sizes[size], 'quantity': 1, 'products_id': product_ids}, headers=headers)

if atc.status_code not in (302, 200):
    print('Error adding item to cart ' + str(atc.status_code) + '..')
else:
    print('ATC Successful..')
```

[image: 403 error]

[image: Headers and form data]

The second image is the headers and the form data that has to be in the post request which I am pretty sure I am passing them correctly.

Comment: Can you share the version of the script which is working? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: I just tried to run the previous script as well and I am receiving a 403 error which I was not receiving before I am thinking there might be something with my ip maybe "banned" from the site but I can still access the site and add items to my cart so I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, I didn't have correct headers I just fixed them.

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'www.colorskates.com',
    'path': product_atc[27:len(product_atc)],
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'referer': product,
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are receiving a `403 Forbidden` error. This means that you are not authorized to access the resource you are requesting.

```
The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it
```

To fix it, you will have to reference and use the authorization scheme used by the API you are requesting from.

Comment: So if I run the script with proxies added will the request most likely go through? Because right now I am running my script on local and I can still access the site and add things to my cart.

Comment: It would likely be an auth token passed as a header. How you authenticate with an API really just depends on the API you're using